# Android Studio Inspections doesn't work correctly

Tags: android, android-studio

When I run inspect on my code it shows a warning like this:

```
Property "isLoading" is never used
```

Even though I am using that property. There are no problems with code, everything works fine, but this issue annoys me, what should I do?

You can see both warning and usage of that property in the photo below:

[image: 1]

Comment: Can You show some code where You init and use `isLoading`? You can `Suppress` this warning: `Alt` + `Enter` and You should see the option for this.

Comment: @iknow, it is not that I want to suppress that warning. How can I get rid of this totally?

Comment: So You want to turn off this warning for the whole project?

Comment: I wanted to get rid of these false warnings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to file -> Invalidate Cache/Restart
2. Click on Invalidate Cache/Restart, a menu pops up
3. On the menu, click on Invalidate Cache and Restart
   // Wait for android studio to restart.

Answer (score 2):

If the answer above doesn't work,
Go to your local drive -- Users -- Android Studio -- System
and delete the caches folder, then open android studio.

Answer (score 1):

I made an enormous mistake.  I assumed Android Studio knew what it was doing when it said it found unused resources and I let it remove them all.   It removed much needed XML id tags, it removed drawables, launcher icons.... what a mess.  Has no one in Android studio land addressed this egregious set of errors?  I spent a far too much time undoing all the things "Inspect code" said was wrong and I let fix only to find the app fails.

Lesson learned - never assume Android Studio knows what it is doing when it comes to inspections. Always check each before taking their often erroneous suggestion